# prerender.io and asp.net core verification failed

Tags: asp.net-core, seo, single-page-application, prerender

I used aurelia (single page application) to create a website. Since SEO meta tags are added during runtime on client side search engines cant pick up these tags.
I found prerender.io as solution for this problem, however I just cant get it to verify my application.

[image: Verification failes]

My backend is implemented asp.net core and is running as a app service.
I used this Middleware: https://github.com/dingyuliang/prerender-dotnet/wiki/Prerender-Middleware-for-ASP.NET-Core

My configuration is:

```
{
  "PrerenderConfiguration": {
    "ServiceUrl": "http://service.prerender.io",
    "Token": null,
    "CrawlerUserAgentPattern": null,
    "WhiteListPattern": null,
    "BlackListPattern": "lib|css|js",
    "AdditionalExtensionPattern": null,
    "ProxyUrl": null,
    "ProxyPort": 80
  }
}
```

I also already tried setting the "Token" in the Configuration to the one I can see on the website after login in the upper left corner.
Is there any step I'm missing or are the instructions on the github page incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this github repo ist no longer maintained. Pull requests like https://github.com/dingyuliang/prerender-dotnet/pull/6/commits/77a8cdd8931ee5bf1955f39d03b9ba2150ee5e2c are not going through for years. Im not sure whats going on but the dll in the nuget package is not working (maybe old build?).
The code itself is working however. I ended up copying all files I needed (Constants.cs, PrerenderConfiguration.cs, PrerenderMiddleware.cs, PrerenderMiddlewareExtendsions.cs and WebProxy.cs) merged some new suggestions and added it so my solution. It works now.